# Any HTML code after iframe is not executed using document.write

Tags: javascript, browser, iframe, document.write

While I was trying to insert an iframe using documnet.write in IE, I got success. But, any html code after that is not executed.

```
document.write("<div>Hello</div><iframe ..../><div>Bye Bye</div>");
```

Here "Bye Bye" string is not executed.

For an instant check you can type in your browser url

```
javascript:document.write("<div>Hello</div><iframe ..../><div>Bye Bye</div>");
```

After doing trial and error, I found that if I close the iframe tag in the following way, it works.

```
<iframe ...></iframe> instead of <iframe  ...  />
```

Now, the problem is "I do not have any opportunity to change the `<iframe  ../>` to `<iframe .. ></iframe>`". Looking for your kind advice.

Comment: @Pekka <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: aww, this may be unsolvable. You have absolutely no way of changing the string? I think there is a similar issue with `<script/>` tags in XHTML documents breaking IE, I can remember the discussion but I can't find it right now.

Comment: What a great question!! You just solved a problem I was having with an <iframe ... /> tag.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to change the string before it is sent to `document.write` then you could modify the markup yourself like so:

```
markup = "<div>Hello</div><iframe ..../><div>Bye Bye</div>"
markup = markup.replace(/<iframe([^>]*?)\/>/g, '<iframe$1></iframe>')
document.write(markup);
```

Comment: This is what he says he can't do, but it might well be the only way, so +1 for the code example

Comment: I was under the impression that the generation of the string containing the `<iframe.../>` was not under his control, but inserting it into the DOM via `document.write` might be.

Comment: @Brian though I have said that I do not have any chance to change the code,but I found your code quite helpful.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Sorry it didn't actually solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any opportunity to change both the string (i.e. you can not read it beforehand) and the `document.write` part of the code, I assume you at least have permission to edit/insert some code in the document (or else you should not have this question as you can literally do nothing at all).

That way, try tempering the `document.write()` method by inserting some code before things happen:

```
document.write=function(str){
    str=str.replace(/<iframe([^>]*?)\/>/ig,'<iframe$1></iframe>');
    return document.writeln(str);
}
```